# R Shiny - Dynamic Filtering from a CSV File - Rows Go Missing

Tags: r, shiny, filtering, rows, missing-data

When using filtering and the `verbatimTextOutput` function in R Shiny, rows go seemingly go missing when I select more than one of the input choices in my `checkboxGroupInput`.

Below is my code.  Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

```
infantmort <- read.csv("infantmort.csv", header = TRUE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("regioninputID",
                     "Select Region(s)",
                     choices = unique(infantmort$whoregion)
  ),

  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput("regionoutputID"), width = "auto", height = "auto"
  )    
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  dataset <- reactive({ 
    as.data.frame(infantmort %>% select(whoregion, year, deathsinthousands) %>% 
      filter(whoregion == input$regioninputID) )


  })

  output$regionoutputID <- renderPrint({ dataset()


  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: infantmort CSV file]

[image: One option selected - notice all 8 data points are visible]

[image: Two options selected - there should be 16 data points visible but there are only 8]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your filter from == to %in%

The following should do the trick

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  dataset <- reactive({ 
    as.data.frame(infantmort %>% select(whoregion, year, deathsinthousands) %>% 
      filter(whoregion %in%  input$regioninputID) )
  })
```